# how to find a representing matrix and to show that $(T_P)^*=T_{P^*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

i can't solve this question correctly. could you help me with it please?

a) let $V=M_{n \times n}^C$ be the standard inner product space, and $P \in V$ be an invertible matrix. we'll define a linear transformation(mapping) as following $T_p:M_{n \times n}^C \to M_{n \times n}^C$ defined by $T_pX=P^{-1}XP$ for every $X \in V$prove that $(T_P)^*=T_{P^*}$

b)let $T_p:M_{2 \times 2}^C \to M_{2 \times 2}^C$ defined by $T_pX=P^{-1}XP$ when $P=\begin{pmatrix}i&1\\ -1&-i\end{pmatrix}$. find the matrix that defines $(T_P)^*$ in the standard base of $M_{2 \times 2}^C$

what i did:

a)since P follows $P*P^{-1}=P^{-1}P=I$, i put it in $T_pX=P^{-1}XP$, but i don't get that $(T_P)^*=T_{P^*}$

b)i tried to calculate P using the given mapping(transformation),in order to find the matrix that represents $(T_P)^*$ under the basic standart of $M^C_{2 
 \times 2}$(since as far as i know $T_P(X)=AX$ (where A is the desired matrix), but still couldn't find it.

please help me show $(T_P)^*=T_{P^*}$ and find the matrix that defines $(T_P)^*$

thank you very much for helping

Comment: Do you know what the standard inner product on $V$ is?  That is how to calculate $(T_P)^*$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$
I believe the standard inner product on complex matrices is
$$
    \left<X,Y\right> = \tr(XY^*)
$$
where $Y^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $Y$.  Using the identity 
$\tr(ABA^{-1}) = \tr(B)$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \left<T_P X,Y\right>
    &= \tr(P^{-1} X P Y^*)
     = \tr(PP^{-1} X P Y^*P^{-1})
     = \tr(X P Y^*P^{-1})
  \\&= \tr(X ((P^{-1})^*Y P^*)^*)
     = \tr(X ((P^*)^{-1}Y P^*)^*)
  \\&= \left<X,T_{P^*} Y\right>
\end{align*}
This establishes that $(T_P)^* = T_{P^*}$.

For (b), I believe the standard basis of $V$ is
\begin{align*}
    E_{11} &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
    &E_{12} &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
    &E_{21} &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
    &E_{22} &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
For each matrix $E$, you need to compute $T_{P^*}E$ and decompose it in the basis
$\mathcal{B} = \left\{E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}\right\}$.  Using a crude [Sage worksheet](https://cocalc.com/projects/77102825-e295-4667-b66f-6775afeb829e/files/how%20to%20find%20a%20representing%20matrix.sagews), I computed
$$
    \left[T_{P^*}\right]_{\mathcal B}
    = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
         1 & -i & i & 1 \\
         i & -1 & -1 & -i \\
        -i & -1 & -1 & i \\
         1 &  i & -i & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The adjoint operator $T_P^*$ is defined by $\langle T_PX,Y\rangle=\langle X,T_P^*Y\rangle$. Obtain that $\langle T_PX,Y\rangle=P^{-1}XP:Y=\sum_{ijkl}P^{-1}_{ij}X_{jk}P_{kl}Y_{il}=\sum_{ijkl}(P^{-1})^*_{ji}X_{jk}P^*_{lk}Y_{il}=\sum_{ijkl}X_{jk}(P^{-1})^*_{ji}Y_{il}P^*_{lk}=\langle X,(P^{-1})^*YP^*\rangle=\langle X,(P^{*})^{-1}YP^*\rangle=\langle X,T_{P^*}Y\rangle$.

Therefore we deduce that $(T_P)^*=T_{P^*}$. Now for (b) you can directly use the result from (a).

Comment: I should say I did not conclude the complex case, but it is infact an analogon by using complex conjugates, you can try it yourself as an exercise.